# Выстраивание элементов

Tags: html, css

Как выстроить элементы как на скриншоте?

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Гляньте](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/2E4dH/), может такой вариант подойдет. Минимум CSS-кода, но учтите, что используется CSS3.

Comment: То, что нужно. :3
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

два родительских div-a (колонки)<br>
внутри div-ы с контентом с нужным margin-top/bottom<br>
?

Comment: В будущем планируется выводить это все из БД.
Идея хорошая, но не для этого случая. Спасибо.

Comment: так а в чем проблема из БД выводить в div-ы ?

Answer (score 1):

Плагин Masonry - самое оно. Элементы можно выстраивать как душе угодно.
http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

Ну, и как следствие, плагин Isotope - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Возьму на заметку...

Answer (score 0):

Скриншота не увидел. Простите.

Сбоку - position absolute, который при скролле меняется на fixed с определенной высоты.
В чентре просто накиданы дивы, например, при помощи float.
Сиськи - задний фон, он устанавливается при помощи background-image.

Что еще?

Comment: Странно... Скриншот должен работать...

Немного не понимаю. Можете сделать какие - нибудь простенькие примеры?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно пригодится [jQuery.Columnizer](https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin/blob/master/src/jquery.columnizer.js) ?